# How to unsubscribe from firebase using function components and react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-redux

Anyone have any examples how I can unsubscribe from onSnapshot from firebase using react-redux for a react native app using function components?

Comment: you can dispatch an action and inside that action, you can perform the unsubscription

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the unsubscribe method from the useEffect destructor callback.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const subscription = GET_SUBSCRIPTION
    return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
});
```